# Algorithm to best match item pairs given similarity score

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I am trying to match two lists of products by name.

Products come from different websites, and theirs names may vary from one website to the other in many subtle ways, e.g. *"iPhone 128 GB"* vs *"Apple iPhone 128GB"*.

The product lists intersect, but are not equal and one is not a superset of the other; i.e. some products from list `A` are not in list `B`, and vice versa.

**Given an algorithm that compares two strings** (product names) and returns a similarity score between 0 and 1 (I already have a satisfactory implementation here), **I'm looking for an algorithm that performs an optimal match of list `A` to list `B`**.

In other words, I think I'm looking for an algorithm that maximizes the sum of all similary scores in the matches.

Note that a product from one list must be matched to at most one product from the other list.

### My initial idea

- for each product in `A`, get the similary with each product in `B`, and retain the product that yields the highest score, provided that it exceeds a certain threshold, such as `0.75`. **Match these products.**
- if the product with the highest score was already matched to another product in `A` earlier in the loop, take the second-to-highest, provided that it exceeds the threshold above. **Match to this one instead**.

etc.

My worry with this native implementation is that if there's a better match later in the loop, but the product from `B` has already been assigned to another product from `A` in a previous iteration, the matching is not optimal.

### An improved version

To ensure that the product is matched to its highest similarity counterpart, I thought of the following implementation:

- pre-compute the similarity scores for all `A`-`B` pairs
- discard the similarities lower than the threshold used above
- order by similarity, highest first
- for each pair, if neither product `A` nor product `B` has already been matched, **match these products**.

This algorithm should optimally match product pairs, ensuring that each pair got the highest similarity.

My worry is that **it's very compute- and memory-intensive**: say I have 5,000 products in both lists, that is 25,000,000 similarity scores to pre-compute and potentially store in memory (or database); in reality it will be lower due to the minimum required threshold, but it can still get very large and is still CPU intensive.

### Did I miss something?

Is there a more efficient algorithm that gives the same output as this improved version?

Comment: Assume you would not calculate the score for one particular pair for some algorithmic reason, then you could miss out on an optimal solution (its score could be very high for all we know): so you'll have to calculate all scores.

Comment: Did you hear about [matching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matching) ? About the size, a 5000 x 5000 distance matrix is not that big, it can be handled quite easily if it does not grow too much.

Comment: @trincot Makes sense indeed!

Comment: @m.raynal No I did not hear about these, I'm a newcomer to graph theory, thanks for the pointer. 5000x5000 might still be manageable, but it becomes exponentially harder as the numbers grow. What about 10,000x10,000? 20,000x20,000? I'm starting to understand that I will have no other choice anyway, so part of the solution probably lies in designing the app with reasonable limits in terms of number of products, and frequency of re-matching (which may be needed from time to time as product databases evolve).

Comment: I'm currently working with 200,000 x 200,000, it gets real big and is actually an issue (it takes 250GB to build a distance matrix ...). A way around is to take advantage of the fact that the vast majority of these weights should be really low. So you could define a threshold below which you set the weight to zero, and use a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) representation of your graph. It is a very common data structure used to deal with big graph instances.

Comment: Also, if you don't need an optimal solution, but just a really good one, it is possible to compute decent matchings using randomized algorithms (or eventually [MILP solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)). Because blossom and the likes are really beautiful algorithms, but can become intractable when the instances grow too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model could be reformulated in graph terms: consider a complete weighted [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) graph, where vertices of the first part are names from list A, vertices of the second part are names from list B and edges are weighted with precomputed scores of similarity.

[image]

Now your problem looks really close to the dense [Assignment_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which optimal solution can be found with [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (O(n³) complexity).

If optimal solution is not your final goal and some good approximations to optimum can also satisfy your requirements, try heuristic algorithms for assignment problem, here is another [topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65600/heuristic-algorithms-for-the-dense-assignment-problem) with a brief overview of them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the graph theory! Getting the same answer twice simultaneously makes me confident that I got the right one ;) About the Hungarian algorithm, after looking it up I can see that it has a complexity of `O(n³)` in the best case. If I'm not mistaken, my second algorithm should have a much lower complexity? I'm asking because as I said in a comment on Cihan Ceyhan's answer, I don't even know which of the two algorithms would translate into most accurate matches in this specific case.

Comment: `O(n³)` complexity is a cost for optimum solution, if some good approximation to optimum can satisfy your requirements, try heuristic algorithms for assignment problem, here is another [topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65600/heuristic-algorithms-for-the-dense-assignment-problem) with brief overview of them. Moreover, you can compare your second heuristic algorithm with them to check which one is better for you in general.

Comment: Yup Hungarian method is a little expensive, but optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Your second algorithm should provide a decent output, but it's not optimal. Check the following case:

```
Set0 Set1 
A    C
B    D

Similarities:
A-C = 900
A-D = 850
B-C = 850
B-D = 0

Your algorithm's output: [(A,C), (B,D)]. Value 900.
Optimal output: [(A,D), (B,C)]. Value 1700.
```

The problem you are working with is exactly the [Assigment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which is "finding, in a weighted bipartite graph, a matching in which the sum of weights of the edges is as large as possible". You can find many ways to optimally and efficiently solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my algorithm is *not* optimal! I'm wondering in this specific case though what would yield the best results: maximum sum, or prioritize high values as in my implementation? I guess only a benchmark against known correct matches would tell.